# Shell Script null check doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, do-while

I am new to shell scripting. My issue is the loop isn't breaking on the condition provided since the if else doesn't seem to work for the null check.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=100
file_name="table-${count}.json"


download_command=(SOME_COMMAND)


continue=true
while "$continue"; do
    echo "${download_command[@]}"
    "${download_command[@]}" > ${file_name}
    next_token=$(jq .NextToken ${file_name})
    count=$((count+100))
    file_name="table-${count}.json"
    echo $next_token
    download_command=(MODIFIED_COMMAND_TO_USE_NEXT_TOKEN)

    if [[ -z $next_token ]]
    then
        continue=false
        break
    else
        echo "I am here"
    fi
    echo $continue
done
```

So, even when my next_token is printing as null, I still see the if condition going in the else block and printing 'I am here'. And the loop continues. I need to break the while loop when next_token is null.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of your script and run it again to see what values the variables have, etc. If you still don't see the problem then post the output of that here (minimal output from a minimal script that demonstrates your problem).

Comment: Shell variables don't have a concept of null. You probably have the four letter string `null` , and if you want to recognize that then you have to do a string comparison

Comment: @thatotherguy I replaced the null check with a proper string comparison and it works now. But, could you tell me why this website tells way of null check in shell script when you say that shell variables dont have a concept of null. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-find-out-if-a-variable-has-null-value-or-not/

Comment: To debug, change your line `echo $next_token` to `echo $next_token | hexdump -C`. If `$next_token` is null, you will see only `0a` in the hexdump output.

Comment: @TAnna It appears to be keyword spamming for SEO reasons, hoping to capture clicks from people using terminology from other languages in their bash searches. The [next article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-script-check-if-variable-is-empty/) is basically a copy of that one, but this time using "empty" instead of "null".

Comment: Oh ok thanks for taking a look. I was simply following it before. Thanks again for resolving the issue.